# Measure Total Runtime of Hadoop Mapreduce Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to measure the total execution time of my MapReduce program, from when I run my program from terminal using hadoop -jar etc until it complete. Can I do it like using Java System.currentTimeMillis in the start and the end of driver main class and then just do end-start? 
I'm not sure it will output the right execution time in the fully distributed mode. Is there a better way? I don't want to use any tools, I want the return value of this execution time. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody that have the same question I already get the answer for this through my own experiment. So the answer is yes you can use currentTimeMillis at the start and end of the main class.